# Reduce the size of a compiled dylib on MacOS

Tags: xcode, macos, dylib

I have licensed a library from a 3rd party (LibXL) that I want to use in my own application. I received an already compiled dylib file and headers.

The problem is that this library is 37MB large! It's a fat library including code for PPC (32bit) and Intel (32bit+64bit). I managed to reduce the file size to 25MB by removing the PPC part with lipo, but that's still huge! My application is only around 5MB large and it seems ridiculous to include a 25MB library that's only needed for a small part of my application.

Does anybody have an idea how to reduce the size of the compiled library? Is it possible to somehow statically link a dylib file so I can strip unused symbols?

Is the huge file size due to debug symbols or something like that inside the dylib? Is there any unnecessary stuff that can be stripped inside dylibs?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running `strip` on it?

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/strip.1.html

Comment: That shaved about 1MB off. Said `strip: symbols referenced by relocation entries that can't be stripped in` (+long list of symbols) Still leaves 24MB :(

Comment: If you can get the source and Xcode project from the original devs, you can probably shrink it down a lot more, but with only a binary you probably can't get much smaller. And a static-linked configuration would probably be massively smaller, as you'd get dead-stripping.

Comment: I asked the company, they were very helpful and provided me with a static library, so the problem with this specific library is solved. However, I still have a few dylibs from other sources that I would also love to make smaller...